# Como alinear derecha css?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Buenas estoy realizando un diseño en css , prácticamente es es un circulo y adentro del circulo introducir un numero, lo malo que cuando lo realizo todo los círculos se me hace hacia abajo.Quisiera que coloquen como la ultima imagen osea al costado

Aqui esta el codigo en css

```
/* Círculos de colores numerados */
span.red {
  background: red;
   border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.grey {
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.green {
  background: #5EA226;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.blue {
  background: #5178D0;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.pink {
  background: #EF0BD8;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}
```

HTML de los circulos

```
<h1><span class="grey">1</span>Un circulo gris con un número interior</h1>

<h1><span class="red">2</span>Un circulo rojo con un número interior</h1>

<h1><span class="blue">3</span>Un circulo azul con un número interior</h1>

<h1><span class="green">4</span>Un circulo verde con un número interior</h1>

<h1><span class="pink">5</span>Un circulo rosa con un número interior</h1>
```

por lo cual cuando lo ejecuto me sale de esta manera 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero yo quisiera que me salga asi PF su ayuda o en que estoy fallando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El problema es que h1, por defecto, la mayoría de navegadores lo renderizan con estos valores:

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.67em;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Como ves tiene la propiedad `display:block`. De ahí que se te esté mostrando cada elemento como un bloque entero.

Una opción es cambiar el `display` del `h1` a `inline`:

```
h1{
  display:inline;
}
```

Aunque tienes que tener en cuenta que al tener al lado del círculo un texto, te saltará de línea, como puedes ver aquí:

```css
/* Círculos de colores numerados */
h1{
  display:inline;
}
span.red {
  background: red;
   border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.grey {
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.green {
  background: #5EA226;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.blue {
  background: #5178D0;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.pink {
  background: #EF0BD8;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="grey">1</span>Un circulo gris con un número interior</h1>

<h1><span class="red">2</span>Un circulo rojo con un número interior</h1>

<h1><span class="blue">3</span>Un circulo azul con un número interior</h1>

<h1><span class="green">4</span>Un circulo verde con un número interior</h1>

<h1><span class="pink">5</span>Un circulo rosa con un número interior</h1>
```

Si sólo quieres mostrar los círculos, quedaría así:

```css
/* Círculos de colores numerados */
h1{
  display:inline;
}
span.red {
  background: red;
   border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.grey {
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.green {
  background: #5EA226;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.blue {
  background: #5178D0;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.pink {
  background: #EF0BD8;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="grey">1</span></h1>

<h1><span class="red">2</span></h1>

<h1><span class="blue">3</span></h1>

<h1><span class="green">4</span></h1>

<h1><span class="pink">5</span></h1>
```

E incluso podrías ahorrarte el `h1` y jugar con la propiedad `font-size`. Te dejo este ejemplo con distintos tamaños:

```css
span.red {
  background: red;
   border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:3em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.grey {
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:3em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.green {
  background: #5EA226;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:4em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.blue {
  background: #5178D0;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:5em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.pink {
  background: #EF0BD8;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}
```

```html
<span class="grey">1</span>

<span class="red">2</span>

<span class="blue">3</span>

<span class="green">4</span>

<span class="pink">5</span>
```

Comment: Excelente muchas Gracias por su explicación